# compile .h file

Tags: c++, makefile

how can i include a re-compilation/update for my own ".h" files within my makefile.

This is my makefile:

```
COMPILER = g++
SOURCES =  main.cpp 
APP = executable/main

OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

all: $(SOURCES) $(APP) 

$(APP): $(OBJECTS)
    $(COMPILER) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.o $(APP)
```

suppose now i want to re-compile the project but i just modified whatever.h and whatever1.h. these files are included in the header of main.cpp.

Comment: You add a dependancy between the source files and the header files.  makedepend (from package imake) can do this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It won't do any good to add these files to the list of dependencies of `$(APP)`.** That will cause Make to relink (that is, build `main` out of `main.o`) but not recompile (that is, build `main.o` out of `main.cpp`, `whatever.h` and `whatever1.h`). The behavior of the executable will not change-- it will not reflect the changes you've made to the headers.

You should add these files to the list of prerequisites of the *object file*:

```
main.o: whatever.h whatever1.h
```

Comment: Additionally you can pass a command line option to your C compiler to generate a dependency file. You should !include this file in your makefile.

Comment: @harper: yes, but that's an advanced technique; the OP is clearly a beginner.

Answer (score -1):

Add header files in your app dependency list:

```
COMPILER = g++
SOURCES =  main.cpp
HEADERS = whatever.h whatever1.h
APP = executable/main

OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

all: $(SOURCES) $(APP) 

$(APP): $(OBJECTS) $(HEADERS)
    $(COMPILER) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.o $(APP)
```